# How to I prove this fact about two sided ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I need to show the following claim:

> Show that every two sided ideal of $Mat_{2,2}(\mathbb{Q})$ is either trivial or $Mat_{2,2}(\mathbb{Q})$

I wanted to do this as follows:

Let us assume that $I$ is an ideal of $Mat_{2,2}(\mathbb{Q})$ and $I$ is nontrivial. I claim that the Identity matrix is in $I$. But I somehow don't see how to show this. Could someone help me?
Because I thought that I could take a nontrivial matrix $M$ in I and then it's inverse is in $Mat_{2,2}(\mathbb{Q})$. But then since $I$ is an ideal then $M\cdot M^{-1}=Id$  which is in I. But this only works if all the entries of $M$ are nonzero, what if for example $m_{1,1}, m_{1,2}$ are zero?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This fact isn’t true unless your only considering two sided ideals.

Comment: oh yes sorry it should be a two sided ideal. I corrected it, could you help me nevertheless?

Comment: If you have a non-zero matrix, say maybe entry (1,1) is non-zero, then you can premultiply by a suitable matrix to have $[1, 0; 0, 0]$. Then you can multiply that by a suitable matrix to get $[0, 0; 0, 1]$. Add them up to get $[1, 0; 0, 1]$. Let me know if you need a lot more details, because indeed I have omiited quite a lot.

Comment: but what if two entries are non-zero and the rest is zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $I$ is a two-sided ideal of $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb Q)$. Let $0\neq A\in I$. We consider two cases:

Case 1: $\operatorname{rank}(A)=2$. Then we can perform row/column operations to $A$ to get $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\in I$. Therefore $I=M_{2\times2}(\mathbb Q)$.

Case 2: $\operatorname{rank}(A)=1$. Then we can perform row/column operations to $A$ to get $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\in I$ and $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\in I$. Therefore $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)+\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\in I$, and hence, $I=M_{2\times2}(\mathbb Q)$.

Comment: thank you, do we also need to assume that I is a two sided ideal and it is unequal to the whole wring, or is this trivial since then the only possibility is that I is trivial?

Comment: I showed that if $I$ is not the zero ideal (a proper proof should explicitly state this), then $I$ is the entire ring. Therefore the zero ideal and the entire ring are the only possibilities.

Comment: ah okey makes sense thank you!